# Получить «реальные» миллиметры в CSS на не-high-DPI устройстве

Tags: css, вёрстка

Сразу скажу, что я не фронтендер.  Есть задача: отобразить на экране лист
формата A4 с точностью до миллиметра (в пределах определённой погрешности).
Читаю [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#absolute_length_units):

> *For low-dpi devices, the unit `px` represents the physical reference pixel;
> other units are defined relative to it.  Thus, `1in` is defined as `96px`,
> which equals `72pt`. The consequence of this definition is that on such
> devices, dimensions described in inches (`in`), centimeters (`cm`), or
> millimeters (`mm`) don't necessary match the size of the physical unit with
> the same name.*
>
> *For high-dpi devices, inches (`in`), centimeters (`cm`), and millimeters
> (`mm`) are the same as their physical counterparts. Therefore, the `px` unit
> is defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).*

При этом определения понятия «_high-dpi_» или «_high-resolution_» я не нашёл, но
96 dpi — это явно не оно.  Нынешний вариант вёрстки, который **не** отображает
верный размер на устройстве:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB" xml:lang="en-GB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
html { background-color: grey; }
body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 297mm;
  width: 210mm;
  margin: 1cm auto;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть ли возможность сделать миллиметры «настоящими» для таких устройств без
*JavaScript*?  Или, если с ним, то как?

Comment: Не получите реальные сантиметры никак. В Вебе существует множество величин, в том числе и mm, cm вы можие и в них указать, попробуйте их задать и на разных мониторах будет разный результат при одинаковом dpi. я проверял с такими величинами: cm, mm, Q, in, pc, pt, px, em, ex, ch, rem, ih
Можите сами потестить https://codepen.io/gregOnCodePen/pen/dyOXGmb

Comment: Это если не рассматривать девайсы у которых настроена система для слабовидящих с масштабом 120% к примеру

Comment: Но можно потанцевать и получить неопределенный и не гарантированный результат [ответ 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202560/how-to-set-a-dimension-in-real-life-units-like-cm-or-mm) [ответ 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650413/pixel-to-mm-equation)